# First time variable is stored it is Undefined, every other time it works? Uses jQuery, JavaScript, Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

**This is part of a function:**

```
var editid;   
$("div.editable").click(function(e) {   
    if ($currentInput == null)   
        return;    

    var css = GetCssProperties();    
    $(this).css(css);
    editid = $(this).attr("id");
    $currentInput = null;
    $("label").html("");
});
```

**I think that the problem is here. If need be, I will post the entire thing.**

Basically, the first time that var editid is stored, it is an undefined value.

The variable is send to a PHP page, and I had it echo the result back on the page.

**Without fail, the first time that it stores its value onclick is "undefined" and every other time it stores the appropriate value.**

Here is the entire thing:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
var $currentInput = null;

$("#border_button, #background_color_button, #opacity_button").click(function() {
    if ($currentInput == null) {
        $currentInput = $(this).prev();
        $("label").html($currentInput.attr("id"));
    }
});

var editid;
$("div.editable").click(function(e) {
    if ($currentInput == null)
        return;

    var css = GetCssProperties();    
    $(this).css(css);
    editid = $(this).attr("id");
    $currentInput = null;
    $("label").html("");
});

function GetCssProperties() {
    if ($currentInput == null) return null;

    var value = $currentInput.val();


    if ($currentInput.attr("id") == "background-color") {
        ajaxStyle(value, 1, editid)
        return {
        "background-color": value
        }
    }
    if ($currentInput.attr("id") == "border-radius") {
        ajaxStyle(value, 2, editid)
        return {
        "border-radius": value
        }
    }
    if ($currentInput.attr("id") == "opacity") {
        ajaxStyle(value, 3, editid)
        return {
        "opacity": value
        }
    }
}

});
```

Comment: Do you have a live demo we can look at, or play with? Perhaps on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), just to replicate the problem.

Comment: it seems like you try to implement PHP variable convention to javascript - `$`

Comment: I can put it on JS Fiddle but it uses PHP. I will add the entire function

Comment: Are you expecting the variable in $currentinput to be fed from PHP or is it a global variable in javascript?

Comment: currentinput is from an HTML input

<input type="text" id="border-radius" value="20px" />   
<div id="border_button">BORDER RADIUS</div>   
<input type="text" id="background-color" value="red" />   
<div id="background_color_button">Background</div>   
<input type="text" id="opacity" value=".5" />   
<div id="opacity_button">Opacity</div>

Comment: the function with parameters: ajaxStyle(value, 3, editid) uses ajax to send the value to a php page, and the parameters (value, 3, editid) are stored in a mysql database. The results are also shown on the page in a div using innerHTML. It displays the results fine, except for the first time where the value of the variable editid comes up undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call GetCssProperties() before you set the value of the variable.
By this the first time the variable will be undefined if you try to access it inside GetCssProperties(), because you have globally declared it, but it still has no value.

Change the order to this:

```
 editid = $(this).attr("id");
 var css = GetCssProperties();
```

Comment: Fantastic!
I can't believe I overlooked that. Thank you very much!